# How can I use CSS3DRenderer in a-frame?

Tags: aframe

I am trying to reproduce this example in a-frame:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=you#css3d_youtube

According to the code is using **CSS3DRenderer** but I couldn't find how to use it with a-frame.  This is my try

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('embed-html', {
     schema: {
        targetUrl: {type: 'string', default: 'https://www.google.com/'}
     },
     init: function () {

        renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        this.el.sceneEl.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

     },

  });
```

But my scene is stuck after that.

Comment: FYI, the CSS3DRenderer won’t work in VR mode. Only canvas based content like WebGL can be rendered in stereo.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos Thanks you for your help.  I will tell that to my client. I will offer him the canvas based version, I guess...I can use a-frame for that.  I will just disable the VR button option.   But I have to figured out how to use CSS3DRenderer  in aframe.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos is possible use Aframe with CSS3DRenderer ? What problems could happen?

Answer (score 0):

There are better options for styling in a-frame, but here is a CSS-Simulated [solution](https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-html-shader).
However I personally didn't use this and write my own custom object